# WIth jquery, if a div has 2 classes in it, can I still add events to it?

Tags: jquery

If a div tag looks like:

```
<div class="class1 class2">blah</div>
```

Isn't this suppose to still work?

```
$(".class2").bind("click", .... );
```

Or does having multiple classes for a element screw things up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this will still work regardless of how many classes are on the tag.

Answer (score 1):

Should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that will work fine as long as you are aware that it will bind the click event for every element that has ".class2" set.

Why?  What's happening?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple classes on an element are valid.  The following should illustrate some examples to help understand the JQuery class selector.

```
<div class="class1">one</div>
<div class="class2">two</div>
<div class="class1 class2">three</div>
```

Then

```
//will bind to the first and third div    
$(".class1").bind("click", .... );

//will bind to the second and third driv
$(".class2").bind("click", .... );

//will bind to only the third div, you get only elements that have BOTH classes
$(".class1.class2").bind("click", ....);

//will bind to all divs, you get elements with class1 along with elements with class2
$(".class1, .class2").bind("click", ....);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code in both IE8 and Firefox 3.5.3, and it works perfectly.

If it's not working for you, there must be some other reason for that.